# Angular 6: variable is undefined in service after calling from other component

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components, undefined

i have 2 components login and messenger component and  1 service called as chat service which is in login component.

now the problem is that when i call the chatservice from login component and set the value of socket variable, it updates the variable. but after when i call the other method(recievetextMessage()) of chat service from messenger component, the value of socket variable is undefined. The code is below.

**chatservice**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


Injectable();

export class chatservice {


socket:any;  // the variable that i am updating
test :any;
constructor() {

}

socketId = () => {

    this.socket = io(''); //updating of variable from login component is here
    console.log(this.socket);
    let observable = new Observable<{ id: any }>(observer => {
        this.socket.on('socketId', (data) => {
            observer.next(data);
        });
        return () => { this.socket.disconnect(); }
    });

    return observable;
}

sendtextmessage(data) {
    this.socket.emit('sendtextMessage', data);
}

recievetextMessage = () => { // called from messenger component
    console.log(this.socket); // gives undefined
    console.log(this.test);
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
        console.log(this.test);
        console.log(this.socket);
        this.socket.on('recievetextMessage', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            observer.next(data);
        });
        return () => { this.socket.disconnect(); }
    });

    return observable;
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you make your call . Can you add the code of your login component?

Comment: actually the login component call the socket server. socket server then calls the login component chatservice.

Comment: Who is providing the service ? it's look like there is 2 differents instance of your chatService. How do you use the service inside your component